# I can't get the IP device with react-native

Tags: react-native

I am doing a component for a react-native application which must get the IP address of the device. The app returns three errors, but I don't find any fault in the code, I believe that they are due to a fail configuration:

[image]

The code is next:

```
import * as Network from 'expo-network';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function IpAddress ()
{
    const [ip, setIp] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { myIP } = await Network.getIpAddressAsync();
            setIp(myIP);
        })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {ip}
        </>
    )
}

export default IpAddress;
```

I am a bit lost. Where is the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: I think your issue is that you are deconstruction the response from the await to { myIP} which likely doesn't exist. Try just const myIP = await .... then console log the response and see what it looks like

Comment: The problem isn't in the code. After use a try-catch instructions, I could see that the problem is the CORS policy which doesn't allow me to get remote resources:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT.
The issue is that I tried to fix it, but I couldn't configure CORS in my program